# Crystal Reports format Time to show Milliseconds

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any way to format a DateTime (from MS SQL) to display milliseconds in Crystal Reports for VS v13?

For example, take a MS SQL DateTime2:

> 1-Feb-2017 11:22:33.456789

And apply formatting in a Crystal report using ToText or any other function, with a format such as "hh:mm:ss.ff", to display this on a report:

> 11:22:33.45

I can format hours, minutes and seconds, but can not work out how to include fractions of a second in the formatting.

Comment: just convert to text and display.. by this you will get full value

Comment: If I use ToText, I can not get fractions of a second to display. I need to do the conversion in Crystal. How do I convert to text, which function/setting?

Comment: There is ToText function in crystal... can you use that a paste the output

Comment: No. Sadly ToText AFAIK does not include milliseconds / fractions of seconds. I need to get the milliseconds somehow in Crystal.